# Calculating the Derivatives of Curvatures on surface

Tags: python, vtk

I want to calculate the derivatives of curvatures on surface using vtk and python. I first calculate the curvatures using:

```
curvatures = vtk.vtkCurvatures()
curvatures.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
curvatures.SetCurvatureTypeToGaussian()
```

and calculate the derivative of curvatures using:

```
Derivativers = vtk.vtkCellDerivatives()
Derivativers.SetInputConnection(curvatures.GetOutputPort())
```

It seems that the results are the same with vtkCurvatures and vtkCellDerivatives.

What should I do to get the derivative of curvature on a surface. Many thanks!

Comment: [numdifftools](https://numdifftools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is correct as it is. But we need to be sure that the curvature point data array is the currently active scalar array. I have attached a input data file that you can save with name `'Test.vtk'`. It has two point data arrays -- PointIds (a scalar array) and PointNormals( a vector array). Then we will calculate Gaussian curvatures which will become the third array of scalars of the point data. We will print names of all the point data arrays irrespective of whether they are scalars or vectors. Then we will explicitly set the `'Gauss_Curvature'` scalar array as the Active Scalar. We will compute Cell Derivatives which will create a Cell Data Vector array called `'ScalarGradient'` which will be the gradient of the curvatures. This will be saved in a file `'Output.vtk'`

```
import vtk

rd = vtk.vtkPolyDataReader()
rd.SetFileName('Test.vtk')
curv = vtk.vtkCurvatures()
curv.SetInputConnection(rd.GetOutputPort())
curv.SetCurvatureTypeToGaussian()
curv.Update()
pd = curv.GetOutput()

for i in range(pd.GetPointData().GetNumberOfArrays()):
    print(pd.GetPointData().GetArrayName(i))
# This will print the following:
# PointIds
# PointNormals
# Gauss_Curvature

# To set the active scalar to Gauss_Curvature
pd.GetPointData().SetActiveScalars('Gauss_Curvature')

curvdiff = vtk.vtkCellDerivatives()
curvdiff.SetInputData(pd)
curvdiff.SetVectorModeToComputeGradient()
curvdiff.Update()

writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName('Output.vtk')
writer.SetInputConnection(curvdiff.GetOutputPort())
writer.Write()
```

gives me the following outputs -- first for the curvature and then the gradient. Notice that the color scale in the two figures are different. So the curvature and derivative values are different although the color scheme makes them look similar.

[image: Curvature]

[image: CurvatureDerivative]

In case you want to reproduce the results, the input vtk file is as below

```
# vtk DataFile Version 4.2
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 72 double
2.0927648978 0.33091989273 -0.39812666792 1.6450815105 0.64303293033 -1.236079764 1.7000810807 1.2495041516 -0.44287861593 
1.0622264471 1.4540269048 -1.1853937884 0.8533187462 0.72833963362 -1.8409362444 0.161573121 1.415272931 -1.6182009866 
-0.4682233113 2.0970647997 -0.17539653223 0.30090053169 1.9778473 -0.80327873468 -0.62604403311 1.746197318 -1.0984268611 
0.62604948422 1.746195345 1.0984268742 0.4682298575 2.0970633231 0.17539654742 -0.30089435724 1.9778482191 0.80327874624 
1.3794219731 1.1031586743 1.2360880686 1.9321437012 0.84755424016 0.44288858377 1.3329709879 1.6469225081 0.39813606858 
-1.3329658439 1.6469266769 -0.39813605266 -1.3794185207 1.1031629885 -1.2360880529 -1.9321410548 0.84756028031 -0.44288857482 
-0.16156870247 1.4152734137 1.6182009959 -1.0622219128 1.4540302146 1.1853938087 -0.85331647216 0.72834227646 1.8409362479 
-1.7000771766 1.2495094572 0.44287862867 -2.0927638628 0.33092642637 0.39812667143 -1.6450795106 0.64303805991 1.2360797754 
0.10502897512 0.5677157381 2.0771002606 -0.54417928828 -0.19289519204 2.0770984773 0.43913323132 -0.37482057542 2.077101172 
1.0574135878 0.37481822068 1.8409414841 1.3064404335 -0.56771795917 1.6182050108 1.7903331906 0.19289323113 1.1854016225 
-0.72812102639 -1.6469234624 1.18539471 -0.20411225533 -1.1031605232 1.8409380189 -1.1448850389 -0.84755547744 1.6181982897 
0.26564737208 -1.7461967516 1.236085002 -0.23207016686 -2.0970637037 0.44288263714 0.75978960067 -1.9778489401 0.39813448025 
1.1992202745 -1.4152750453 1.0984284306 1.5819944619 -1.4540310306 0.17539958384 1.8633106814 -0.72834386503 0.80328466622 
-1.825278792 -0.33092031521 1.0984201446 -2.0502257619 -0.64303229501 0.17538963068 -1.5624229303 -1.2495043655 0.80327527281 
-0.26565282447 -1.7461959014 -1.2360850131 0.23206361633 -2.0970644256 -0.44288265596 -0.7597957797 -1.977846564 -0.39813449851 
-1.1992246997 -1.4152712955 -1.0984284473 -1.5819990123 -1.4540260972 -0.17539960215 -1.8633129661 -0.72833804688 -0.80328468018 
0.20410881451 -1.1031611451 -1.8409380327 1.1448823984 -0.84755903977 -1.6181983017 0.72811588321 -1.6469257176 -1.1853947189 
2.0502237661 -0.64303869999 -0.17538964133 1.5624190405 -1.2495092418 -0.80327529169 1.8252777661 -0.33092600698 -1.0984201511 
-0.43913440065 -0.37481918558 -2.0771011678 -0.10502720377 0.56771608521 -2.0771002475 0.54417868626 -0.19289687027 -2.0770984714 
-1.3064422115 -0.56771386838 -1.6182050202 -1.7903325818 0.19289882961 -1.185401614 -1.057412421 0.3748215375 -1.8409414839 
-0.76083174443 1.3178134523 -1.9919051229 -0.7608358562 -1.3178110596 -1.9919051353 -2.4621262785 3.8465962003e-06 -0.47023127203 
1.5216839818 -2.3645462409e-06 -1.991898872 2.4621262803 -3.846902628e-06 0.47023127288 1.2310617434 -2.1322669408 -0.47022115796 
-1.2310684033 -2.1322631023 0.47022113869 -1.5216839821 2.3661982943e-06 1.9918988726 0.76083174316 -1.3178134534 1.9919051234 
0.76083585779 1.317811059 1.9919051359 -1.2310617441 2.1322669425 0.47022115881 1.2310684021 2.1322631008 -0.47022113785 

POLYGONS 140 560
3 12 14 9 
3 27 69 24 
3 70 21 19 
3 1 53 63 
3 2 14 13 
3 38 36 37 
3 28 68 36 
3 39 67 23 
3 64 38 51 
3 13 14 12 
3 20 24 18 
3 34 35 33 
3 40 41 39 
3 16 58 17 
3 20 18 19 
3 26 27 24 
3 11 6 70 
3 10 14 71 
3 22 39 23 
3 6 10 7 
3 3 5 7 
3 29 64 13 
3 41 30 32 
3 57 45 47 
3 54 61 57 
3 66 30 41 
3 50 43 42 
3 30 33 31 
3 33 35 36 
3 65 37 35 
3 37 36 35 
3 26 68 28 
3 68 33 36 
3 27 28 29 
3 28 36 38 
3 29 28 38 
3 38 37 51 
3 61 48 42 
3 37 65 52 
3 66 34 30 
3 43 65 35 
3 32 30 31 
3 30 34 33 
3 40 39 22 
3 41 32 39 
3 66 41 46 
3 32 67 39 
3 67 32 25 
3 33 68 31 
3 32 31 25 
3 31 26 25 
3 27 26 28 
3 26 31 68 
3 64 29 38 
3 12 69 27 
3 18 9 11 
3 69 12 9 
3 18 24 69 
3 20 67 25 
3 26 24 25 
3 24 20 25 
3 13 12 29 
3 12 27 29 
3 18 11 19 
3 11 9 10 
3 69 9 18 
3 9 14 10 
3 70 6 15 
3 11 10 6 
3 10 71 7 
3 71 14 2 
3 70 15 21 
3 6 8 15 
3 21 17 22 
3 15 8 16 
3 20 23 67 
3 19 11 70 
3 21 23 19 
3 23 20 19 
3 22 17 62 
3 22 23 21 
3 15 17 21 
3 62 40 22 
3 58 57 47 
3 62 17 58 
3 62 47 40 
3 58 16 59 
3 15 16 17 
3 6 7 8 
3 16 60 59 
3 48 54 56 
3 8 5 60 
3 2 1 3 
3 7 5 8 
3 3 1 4 
3 2 3 71 
3 71 3 7 
3 3 4 5 
3 5 55 60 
3 49 50 48 
3 8 60 16 
3 60 55 59 
3 4 55 5 
3 54 57 59 
3 1 63 4 
3 56 55 4 
3 49 48 56 
3 44 45 42 
3 63 56 4 
3 48 61 54 
3 56 54 55 
3 54 59 55 
3 59 57 58 
3 47 62 58 
3 40 46 41 
3 57 61 45 
3 47 45 46 
3 43 34 44 
3 47 46 40 
3 46 44 66 
3 37 52 51 
3 42 48 50 
3 42 43 44 
3 43 35 34 
3 45 44 46 
3 44 34 66 
3 61 42 45 
3 50 65 43 
3 65 50 52 
3 56 63 49 
3 51 52 53 
3 49 63 53 
3 50 49 52 
3 49 53 52 
3 2 0 1 
3 1 0 53 
3 0 51 53 
3 0 64 51 
3 13 64 0 
3 2 13 0 

POINT_DATA 72
SCALARS PointIds vtkIdType
LOOKUP_TABLE default
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 
36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 
45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 
54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 
63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 

NORMALS PointNormals double
0.94738623196 0.18727650058 -0.25958975291 0.78313719053 0.35367076216 -0.51148131227 0.83545291047 0.50824408436 -0.20906072109 
0.47898857295 0.62402000487 -0.61738884061 0.34465195337 0.40584589543 -0.84646567573 0.15649087604 0.66776200195 -0.72773931766 
-0.15609353126 0.97764567412 -0.14086782943 0.059136449433 0.91410106494 -0.40115099829 -0.27742338135 0.85504231805 -0.43810832201 
0.27739675558 0.85505949665 0.43809165386 0.1561128187 0.97764027026 0.14088395868 -0.05910174957 0.91410169764 0.40115467037 
0.6978536347 0.50139725414 0.51146954756 0.85786633279 0.46941626794 0.20907826874 0.63588503517 0.72681646701 0.25959207486 
-0.63587825439 0.72682167945 -0.25959409059 -0.69785435483 0.50138010962 -0.51148537136 -0.85787788306 0.46940090711 -0.20906536337 
-0.15651072102 0.66775823558 0.72773850593 -0.47897825964 0.62400201859 0.61741502054 -0.34463970914 0.40587327082 0.84645753521 
-0.8354604399 0.50822639825 0.20907362693 -0.94738511041 0.18728497536 0.25958773195 -0.78315168201 0.35366155935 0.51146548701 
-0.0042059530133 0.19834561529 0.98012311821 -0.16967339936 -0.10281294988 0.98012266318 0.17387129188 -0.095532679284 0.98012360499 
0.52381294065 0.095528092331 0.84645991446 0.65654796659 -0.19833859028 0.72774073074 0.77988819356 0.10280486141 0.61741846913 
-0.30091501143 -0.72680688867 0.6174155023 -0.17918019275 -0.50140137515 0.8464579845 -0.50004323045 -0.46941965564 0.72773755886 
0.085293841035 -0.8550588207 0.51146786196 -0.022407612419 -0.97764266904 0.20907584885 0.31149794024 -0.91410144601 0.25959117785 
0.60180306843 -0.66776342878 0.4380925359 0.76860432156 -0.62401813766 0.14088563004 0.82118451863 -0.40586818759 0.40115707731 
-0.87920342686 -0.18729607405 0.43808847833 -0.92471829912 -0.35362213463 0.14088098936 -0.76208606823 -0.50823351579 0.40115273655 
-0.08527862936 -0.85505086473 -0.51148369876 0.022426691996 -0.97764498848 -0.20906295701 -0.31150584284 -0.91409817614 -0.25959320919 
-0.60177487516 -0.6677778914 -0.43810921854 -0.76861864432 -0.62400413386 -0.14086951598 -0.82120131764 -0.40583781416 -0.40115341765 
0.17915035572 -0.50139827931 -0.84646613373 0.5000564084 -0.4694043424 -0.72773838139 0.30092542605 -0.72682480482 -0.61738933507 
0.92471333385 -0.3536415386 -0.14086487277 0.7620681671 -0.50826324483 -0.40114907784 0.8792018588 -0.18726442077 -0.43810515655 
-0.17386795802 -0.09554490851 -0.98012300434 0.0041936861197 0.19834885542 -0.98012251507 0.16968233044 -0.10280393451 -0.9801220627 
-0.65654129971 -0.19835764899 -0.72774155087 -0.77990892195 0.10280480888 -0.61739229403 -0.52379534825 0.095552395563 -0.84646805779 
-0.3035934934 0.52568869256 -0.79465866212 -0.30345974591 -0.52576590314 -0.79465866742 -0.98224561547 8.0181630296e-06 -0.18759944248 
0.60705977261 7.7220189155e-05 -0.79465616874 0.98224726985 9.1023794904e-07 0.18759078032 0.49111663606 -0.85065410882 -0.18759540755 
-0.49112361722 -0.85065199031 0.18758673723 -0.60706560357 -2.8418937296e-07 0.79465171803 0.30352977695 -0.52573221141 0.79465421184 
0.30352929122 0.52573248433 0.79465421681 -0.49112519531 0.85065107744 0.18758674521 0.49113052171 0.85064609373 -0.18759539936
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think my problem may be that the scalar array is not the only one and therefore not be activated. Could you tell me how to make the scalar activated. By the way, I meet another problem. After calculating the curvature,how can I get the result array. I want to know all the array names in the result, and then get the result array according to the corresponding array names. Currently, I only find a method using FindAllArrayNames in Cxx, but not in python. Is there any similar way in python. Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated my example to have an input file which has multiple point data arrays. We will explicitly set the curvature array to be the active array before calculating the derivatives. I have also added an example of how to list all the array names of point data.